# Go through all kubernetes Jobs using google cloud functions

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, python-3.7

I'm using kubernetes==10.1.0

My code is in python 3.7 and something like that:

```
from kubernetes import client as kubernetes_client
BatchV1_api = kubernetes_client.BatchV1Api()
api_response = BatchV1_api.list_namespaced_job(namespace="default", watch = False, pretty='true', async_req=False )
```

The problem is I got about 1500 jobs in kubernetes and api_response returns only 20

The goal is to implement program which go throw all jobs and delete old ones by job name as parameter

Any idea why I'm getting only partial data from BatchV1_api.list_namespaced_job function?

Comment: You have 1500 jobs in `default` namespace?

Comment: Yes.It's old jobs which needs to be deleted (currently in dev env). I'm building program which will delete them, but for that goal I need to go over them to decide which one need to be deleted and get only about 20 in the response.

Comment: I don't think you can edit the amount of jobs in the response. Maybe you should contact the guys of the client library over at [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues)